# Performance collapse C++ (std vector bad_allocation)

Tags: c++, performance, vector, graph, nodes

Following code is about searching for neighbours in realtime. As soon as a new node is added to my graph, the function `updateSeqNeighbours` for this node is called. What I know is, that the new node is definitely neighbour to the last one added. In the next step I use this fact to look in the neighbourhood of the previously added node, find the one closest to the new and then search this neighbourhood for the closest neighbour.

I repeat this only for example 3 times, to limit the number of neighbours for one node to 4 to keep a constant time frame for calculation. It works wonderful, except for after ~30 nodes the calculation time increases very fast with every additional node resulting in a `bad_alloc` exception.

```
#ifndef GRAPH_NODE_H_
#define GRAPH_NODE_H_

#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    double x;
    double y;

    Node* nodePrev;

    vector<Node> seqNeighbours;

    //Constructor
    Node();
    Node(double x, double y);
    virtual ~Node();

    //Operator functions
    Node& operator=(const Node& n);

    //Get&Set
    int getID();

    //Public member functions
    void addNeighbour(Node& n);

    bool isSeqNeighbour(int ID);

    int updateSeqNeighbours();

    double distanceTo(Node& n);

private:
    static int count;
    int ID;

    void _setDefaults();
};

int Node::count = 0;

Node::Node() {
    _setDefaults();
}

Node::Node(double x, double y) {
    _setDefaults();
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}

Node::~Node() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

//Operator functions
Node& Node::operator=(const Node& n) {
    if (this != &n) {
        ID = n.ID;
            x = n.x;
            y = n.y;
        seqNeighbours.clear();
        seqNeighbours = n.seqNeighbours;
        nodePrev = n.nodePrev;
    }
    return *this;
}

//Get&Set
int Node::getID() {
    return this->ID;
}

//Public member functions
void Node::addNeighbour(Node& n) {
    seqNeighbours.push_back(n);
}

double Node::distanceTo(Node& n) {
    return sqrt((n.x-x)*(n.x-x) + (n.y-y)*(n.y-y));
}

bool Node::isSeqNeighbour(int ID) {
    for (int i = 0; i < seqNeighbours.size(); i++) {
        if (seqNeighbours[i].getID() == ID) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int Node::updateSeqNeighbours() {
    if (nodePrev == NULL) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        Node seed = *nodePrev;  //previous node as seed
        seqNeighbours.push_back(seed);

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    if (seed.nodePrev == NULL) break;
                    double minDist = 15353453;
                    Node closest;
                    for (int j = 0; j < seed.seqNeighbours.size(); j++) {
                            double dist = distanceTo(seed.seqNeighbours[j]);
                            if (dist < minDist) {
                                    minDist = dist;
                                    closest = seed.seqNeighbours[j];
                            }
                    }
                    if (minDist < 150) {
                            seqNeighbours.push_back(closest);
                    }
                    seed = closest;
            }
            cout << "neighbours = " << seqNeighbours.size() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

void Node::_setDefaults() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    ID = count;
    nodePrev = NULL;
    seqNeighbours.clear();
    count++;
}
#endif /* GRAPH_NODE_H_ */
```

Graph:

```
#ifndef GRAPH_GRAPH_H_
#define GRAPH_GRAPH_H_

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "Node.h"

using namespace std;

class Graph {
public:
    Graph();
    virtual ~Graph();

    vector<Node> list;

    void addNode(Node& n);
    void addSeqNode(Node& n);


private:
    void _setDefaults();
};

Graph::Graph() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

Graph::~Graph() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

void Graph::addNode(Node& n) {
    list.push_back(n);
}

void Graph::addSeqNode(Node& n) {
    if (!list.empty()) {
        n.nodePrev = &list.back();
    }
    n.updateSeqNeighbours();
    list.push_back(n);
}

void Graph::_setDefaults() {
    list.clear();
}


#endif /* GRAPH_GRAPH_H_ */
```

I suspect running out of memory causes this. However 40 nodes with each 4 neighbours doesn't sound much of a problem to me. Anyone any idea what goes wrong?

Edit:
Error in german, so I need to guess:
An exception accured in project prSimulation1.exe of class std::bad_alloc. Adress of Exception: '0x5476016'. Process was stopped.

Comment: Where is the copy constructor for the Node class ? Can you put the crash trace as well ? The use of pointer for nodePrev doesn't look quite right.  Can you put the code which is actually making use of this class ?

Comment: Why can't you use the Debugger?

Comment: @Arunmu : 1) Haven't implemented one yet, do I need it in my current code? 2) Crash message is updated, hope that is what you mean?! 3) Done.

Comment: @Ajay : Using a university software running in borland 6 and really have no clue how to debug with that :D

Comment: @laxn_pander Yes, for the correctness of your code, you need a copy constructor. For NodePrev, you need not do deep copy, just assign the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `seqNeighbours` is `vector<Node>`. That means it stores the neighbours themselves, not pointers to them or their indices.  The copy constructor, therefore, copies all the neighbours.  Copying each neighbour, in turn, requires to copy *its neighbours*, which requires to copy their neighbours, and so on.  Your assignment also copies all the neighbours, which requires to copy their neighbours, and so on.  This means that each copy exponentially increases memory load, until the system is unable to store all the neighbours, neighbours of neigbours etc.

PS: on a side note, a vector called "list" is a bad idea.  It is like a list called "vector", a set called "map", or a cat called Dog.

Comment: Thank you very much. Makes total sense. Your note on that list thing is valid, you might guess I am an engineer not a programmer :D

Comment: You should either make it `vector<Node*>` instead of `vector<Node>`, or remove this field from the Node and store the adjancency matrix in the `Graph` class.  The adjancency matrix may be stored, for instance, as `vector< vector<int> > adj;` , which means that `adj[i][j]` is the index of j-th neighbour of `adj[i]`.